# Access PC storage from phone

Tags: storage

Is there any way to show up my computer's storage in my phone when I plug in my phone using usb cable?
It is similar to auto-mounting of phone storage in pc but different in that it's phone which would be accessing the pc storage.

Comment: Not easily.  USB is a tree structure -- the PC cannot simultaneously act as the host for the phone and allow the phone to take control of its storage.  You'd have to have some sort of service running on each side communicating the information.

Comment: Can we do it without running a service say, file server with its root as root of file system?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  A file server is a service.